# Gmail like listview item remove

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I'm trying to achieve something the Gmail app (ICS) offers on deleting message. I wan't all rows below deleted cell to move up and cover deleted cell.

Here is working animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

        <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

</set>
```

All I came up with so far is this:

```
public static List<View> getCellsBelow(ListView listView, int position) {
    List<View> cells = new ArrayList<View>();       

    for (int i = position + 1; i <= listView.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {
        cells.add(listView.getChildAt(i));
    }

    return cells;
}
```

I gather visible cells bellow the selected cell and then animate them in foreach. I fear this is performance disaster. I also have trouble notify adapter that it should reload it's content. normally I'd call `notifyDataSetChanged` on `onAnimationEnd` but now there are couple of animations playing one after another.

Any suggestions pals? Maybe there is something that allows to animate couple of views stimulatenously?

Comment: A simplest way would be to reduce the height of the deleted row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**: I recommend checking out [this solution](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104755487586666698979/posts/RRTm14JsPQY) by Chet Haase who works at the Android team. Especially if you are not developing for Android 2.3 and lower.

---

This should be exactly what you want.

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
            final View view, final int position, long id) {
        removeRow(view, position);
        return true;
    }
});

private void removeRow(final View row, final int position) {
    final int initialHeight = row.getHeight();
    Animation animation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
            int newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
            if (newHeight > 0) {
                row.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
                row.requestLayout();
            }
        }
    };
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            row.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight;
            row.requestLayout();
            items.remove(position);
            ((BaseAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    animation.setDuration(300);
    row.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Comment: @matthias can you please tell me which view is the one which you are passing in the removeRow method ? is it list view or the my rootview that i inflate from my layout xml !

Comment: It is the list item view.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the ListView I made for this. It's on [Github](https://github.com/yDelouis/SwipeToDeleteListView).

Answer (score 1):

The original author of this published the code as a Gist here: https://gist.github.com/2980593
and here is the original Google+ post from Roman Nurik: https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/Fgo1p5uWZLu

Comment: unforunately it's for API 12+